# What command in bash to search for this string?

Tags: sed, grep, find

`file.txt` contains:

```
aa=testing
sss=whoiam
bbb=findme
```

What command do I use to search for testing and print it?

Expected result:

```
# you search testing
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `grep`:

```
string=testing && grep "$string" file.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null && echo "you search $string"
```

The string "you search testing" is printed when the string "testing" is found somewhere in the file `file.txt`.

- `string=testing`: set the variable `$string`
- `grep "$string" file.txt 2>&1` >/dev/null: `grep` searches for the string in the file. We don't want the output that because both (`stdin` and `stderr`) are redirected to `/dev/null`.
- `echo "you search $string"`: if everything is succesfull, print the string.

Just change the variable `$string` for your pattern.

**Additional quesitions:**

> how about if i want to search the value for aa?

With this oneliner the value of aa is search too. The complete content of the file file.txt is gone trough.

> i mean my reference is aa not its value(testing)?

Use this:

```
string=aa && grep "^$string=" file.txt | awk -F= '{printf "you search %s\n", $2}'
```

This searched for aa as variable name and then prints the value. The output od this would be:

```
you search testing
```

Comment: What is the point of using `export`?

Comment: @Bernhard true, I see. It's not needed to make it an environment variable. Edited, tanks.

Comment: By using `grep`'s `-q` flag (for 'quiet`) mayou can make the oneliner even simpler: `string=testing && grep -q "$string" file.txt && echo "you search $string"`